# Parcel doesn't transpile modern Javascript - newbie

Tags: javascript, babeljs, parceljs, parcel, transpiler

could you please help me to solve this problem? I just can't fugure it out :(
Parcel just doesn't transpile modern JS:

- I've installed Parcel: `npm install --save-dev parcel`
- created a Babel config file such as .babelrc (tried also babel.config.json) and Parcel did NOT pick it up automatically as the documentation said.

When I tried to put `{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}` to babel.config.json, my terminal reports:

```
@parcel/transformer-babel: @babel/preset-env does not support Parcel's targets, which will likely 
result in unnecessary transpilation and larger bundle sizes.

  /Users/zk/Documents/Builds/Yablko/vue 2/babel.config.json:2:15
    1 | {
  > 2 |   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  >   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | }
    4 | 

   Either remove @babel/preset-env to use Parcel's builtin transpilation, or replace with 
     @parcel/babel-preset-env
   Learn more: https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#custom-plugins
```

I've tried to remove `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]` from config, also tried to use `@parcel/babel-preset-env`. Nothing works for me.

I appreciate any help in my learning process. Thank you

Comment: Did you put `.babelrc` in the correct place (application root)?

Comment: yes, I did. When I tried to install "npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler" instead of "npm install --save-dev parcel" transpiling worked. But according to terminal, parcel-bundler is deprecated.